# Anorm SQL Folding a List into a class result

Tags: sql-server, scala, playframework, anorm

please pardon the level of detail.  I'm not completely sure how to phrase this question.

I am new to scala and still learning the intricacies of the language.  I have a project where all the data I need is contained in a table with a layout like this:

```
CREATE TABLE demo_data ( table_key varchar(10), description varchar(40), data_key varchar(10), data_value varchar(10) );
```

Where the table_key column contains the main key I'm searching on, and the description repeats for every row with that table_key.  In addition there are descriptive keys and values contained in the data_key and data_value pairs.

I need to consolidate a set of these data_keys into my resulting class so that the class will end up like this:

```
case class Tab ( tableKey: String, description: String, valA: String, valB: String, valC: String )
object Tab {
 val simple = {
  get[String]("table_key") ~
  get[String]("description") ~
  get[String]("val_a") ~
  get[String]("val_b") ~
  get[String]("val_c") map {
  case tableKey ~ description ~ valA ~ valB ~ valC => Tab(table_key, description, valA, valB, valC)
  }
 }
 def list(tabKey: String) : List[Tab] = {
  DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
   val tabs = SQL(
     """
       SELECT DISTINCT p.table_key, p.description,
          a.data_value val_a,
          b.data_value val_b,
          c.data_value val_c
        FROM demo_data p
             JOIN demo_data a on p.table_key = a.table_key and a.data_key = 'A'
             JOIN demo_data b on p.table_key = b.table_key and b.data_key = 'B'
             JOIN demo_data c on p.table_key = c.table_key and c.data_key = 'C'
        WHERE p.table_key = {tabKey}
      """
     ).on('tabKey -> tabKey).as(Tab.simple *)
  }

  return tabs
 }
}
```

which will return what I want, however I have more than 30 data keys that I wish to retrieve in this manner, and the joins to itself rapidly becomes unmanageable.  As in the query ran for 1.5 hours and used up 20GB worth of temporary tablespace before running out of disk space.

So instead I am doing a separate class that retrieves a list of data keys and data values for a given table key using the "where data_key in ('A','B','C',...)", and now I'd like to "flatten" the returned list into a resulting object that will have the valA, valB, valC, ... in it.  I still want to return a list of the flattened objects to the calling routine.

Let me try to idealize what I'd like to accomplish..

Take a header result set and a detail result set, extract out the keys out of the detail result set to populate additional elements/properties in the header result set and produce a list of classes containing the all the elements of the header result set, and the selected properties from the detail result set.  So I get a list of TabHeader(tabKey,Desc) and for each I retrieve a list of interesting TabDetail(DataKey,DataValue), I then extract out the element where the DataKey == 'A' and put the DataValue element in Tab(valA), and do the same for DataKey == 'B', 'C', ...  After I'm done I wish to produce a Tab(tabKey, Desc, valA, valB, valC, ...) in place of the corresponding TabHeader.  I could quite possibly muddle through this in Java, but I'm treating this as a learning opportunity and would like to know a good way to do this in Scala.

I'm feeling that something with the scala mapping should do what I need, but I haven't been able to track down exactly what.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? You tagged sql-server but you have varchar2 which is NOT a sql-server datatype.

Comment: I suspect this is an EAV table which is why you have to join this table to itself over and over and over.

Comment: Altered question to clarify? The database is SQLServer, and I typed the code in, so sorry about the VarChar2. Rather then a header table and detail table, everything is in one table. I wish to produce one class with the various detail descriptions as properties of the class. I did not design the table, and cannot change the layout. Each data_key that I'm interested in should end up as a property in the class whose value will contain the corresponding data_value. I'm not sure how much clearer I can be about that. Yes it is an EAV table.

Comment: To process SQL result as soon as possible and keep in memory only what's required, you can benefit from using the streaming support of Anorm: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaAnorm ; In master (check 2.3.7), the streaming was updated with fold operations.